# Slope of $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A differential equation $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$. If $(a,b)$ is a point on the curve $y=-e^{-x^2}$, then will a solution to the differential equation through $(a,b)$ have a slope of 0 at $(a,b)$. So this is a solution, calling it $f(x)$, and this solution go through $(a,b)$, then will the solution have a slope of 0 at that point? This question is very difficult and I try to visualize it: There's graph of $-e^{-x^2}$. It's very flat but not at around 0. The differential equation $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$ is the same graph! So I think they have the same slope 0 everywhere.

Comment: The second order term (of $y$) in $y'=1+\exp(x^2)y$ drives the solution away from $y=-\exp(-x^2)$.

Comment: @user10354138 So it's saying this is not slope 0?